# Azure SQL Export via https://portal.azure.com Never Completes

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Have tried exporting our sql database several times, several different copies (regional replication), and we always get a zero byte file in our storage blob account.  No statuses, no error messages.

Any hints?

Edit:  None of the below answers solved my issue.  The issue was there was an invalid view in the database, which was causing the export to silently fail.

Comment: You haven't really given much to go on. Do you have any logs to share? Any info on the portal? Have you considered a support ticket?

Comment: Neither has azure.. there are no logs or status messaging besides it starting.   Support Ticket not available with my subscription.

Comment: Update on this - was a view that would not validate.  Make sure all your views are valid (reference valid column names)

Comment: kevinc.thanks I'm guessing that is my issue, I will need to investigate. Question:how did you determine that was the problem?

Answer (score 11):

Perform the "Export Data-tier Application" task from SQL Server Management Studio instead. This will provide you with detailed progress about the export.

Step by step instructions:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio (2016 or above)
2. Connect to the Azure SQL Server
3. Right click on the required database, choose "Tasks" and "Export Data-tier Application"
4. Follow the wizard

Comment: You could create a VM, install the management studio there (it's a free download) and remote desktop into it. I'm not saying it's a great solution, but it's a workaround. It's been a while since I last tried this from the portal, but at the time it frustrated me enough to try it from Management Studio and the user interface feedback was much better.

Answer (score -1):

> get a zero byte file in our storage blob account. No statuses, no error messages.

This is an expected behavior, this 0 byte file is used to check whether it has permissions to your storage account container. The service will not write out the full BACPAC until the export is complete. it will not save template data to our storage, and we need not to pay for the template data. For this reason, you will see the size of the file is always 0 byte. At currently we have no process bar to show whether the export operation is completed in portal, so please check the resource utilization like following chart. if the line back to the normal level then check your file again.

[image]

Comment: Its been a day for a database that is only 500mb... where are logs or other status?

Comment: i have 3 logs all showing 0 and there is no updates in lat 5 days